# Which of the combined triggers caused job execution in apscheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

**TL;DR:** When [combining triggers](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/combining.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.combining) in APScheduler, is it possible to know which original trigger(s) caused the job to execute?

**Longer story:** I am trying to run tasks which fetch data from devices via SNMP. Some tasks run every 2 minutes, some every 5 minutes, some every 10 minutes... but when the intervals align, it is important to merge those tasks to a single query due to performance reasons.

One way to solve this issue would be to implement a custom [executor](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/executors/base.html#module-apscheduler.executors.base), but that seems a bit more involved. It seems easier to combine the tasks in a single job which gets run on any of the intervals - however, then I need to know *which* interval(s) triggered the job execution. Is there a way to get this information?

Small example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import OrTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
import logging


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger("{}.{}".format(__name__, "base"))


def test_func(*args, **kwargs):
    log.warn("Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: {}, kwargs: {}".format(args, kwargs))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

    # apply config to scheduler:
    intervals = [10, 15, 50]
    trigger = OrTrigger([IntervalTrigger(seconds=sec) for sec in intervals])
    scheduler.add_job(test_func, trigger=trigger, kwargs={"a": 123, "b": 345})

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        log.info("Got exit signal, exiting.")
```

Output:

```
2019-09-08 09:57:59 | INFO | Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
2019-09-08 09:57:59 | INFO | Added job "test_func" to job store "default"
2019-09-08 09:57:59 | INFO | Scheduler started
2019-09-08 09:57:59 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:57:59 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:58:09.453275+02:00 (in 9.998746 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:58:09 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:58:09 | INFO | Running job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:09 CEST)" (scheduled at 2019-09-08 09:58:09.453275+02:00)
2019-09-08 09:58:09 | WARNING | Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: (), kwargs: {'a': 123, 'b': 345}
2019-09-08 09:58:09 | INFO | Job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:09 CEST)" executed successfully
2019-09-08 09:58:09 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:58:19.453275+02:00 (in 9.999404 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:58:19 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:58:19 | INFO | Running job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:19 CEST)" (scheduled at 2019-09-08 09:58:19.453275+02:00)
2019-09-08 09:58:19 | WARNING | Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: (), kwargs: {'a': 123, 'b': 345}
2019-09-08 09:58:19 | INFO | Job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:19 CEST)" executed successfully
2019-09-08 09:58:19 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:58:29.453275+02:00 (in 9.997439 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:58:29 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:58:29 | INFO | Running job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:29 CEST)" (scheduled at 2019-09-08 09:58:29.453275+02:00)
2019-09-08 09:58:29 | WARNING | Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: (), kwargs: {'a': 123, 'b': 345}
2019-09-08 09:58:29 | INFO | Job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:29 CEST)" executed successfully
2019-09-08 09:58:29 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:58:39.453275+02:00 (in 9.997883 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:58:39 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:58:39 | INFO | Running job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:39 CEST)" (scheduled at 2019-09-08 09:58:39.453275+02:00)
2019-09-08 09:58:39 | WARNING | Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: (), kwargs: {'a': 123, 'b': 345}
2019-09-08 09:58:39 | INFO | Job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:39 CEST)" executed successfully
2019-09-08 09:58:39 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:58:49.453275+02:00 (in 9.997841 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:58:49 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:58:49 | INFO | Running job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:49 CEST)" (scheduled at 2019-09-08 09:58:49.453275+02:00)
2019-09-08 09:58:49 | WARNING | Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: (), kwargs: {'a': 123, 'b': 345}
2019-09-08 09:58:49 | INFO | Job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:49 CEST)" executed successfully
2019-09-08 09:58:49 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:58:59.453275+02:00 (in 9.997944 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:58:59 | DEBUG | Looking for jobs to run
2019-09-08 09:58:59 | INFO | Running job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:59 CEST)" (scheduled at 2019-09-08 09:58:59.453275+02:00)
2019-09-08 09:58:59 | WARNING | Which interval(s) caused this job to execute? I only got args: (), kwargs: {'a': 123, 'b': 345}
2019-09-08 09:58:59 | INFO | Job "test_func (trigger: or[interval[0:00:10], interval[0:00:15], interval[0:00:50]], next run at: 2019-09-08 09:58:59 CEST)" executed successfully
2019-09-08 09:58:59 | DEBUG | Next wakeup is due at 2019-09-08 09:59:09.453275+02:00 (in 9.997905 seconds)

2019-09-08 09:59:00 | INFO | Got exit signal, exiting.
```

**EDIT:** note that as the output shows, the intervals are incorrect (scheduler waits for 10s every time, while it should wait first 10s, then 5s, then 5s, then 10s...) - but I guess this is a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, when combining triggers,

> Always returns the earliest next fire time that all the given triggers can agree on. The trigger is considered to be finished when any of the given triggers has finished its schedule.

When using OR, only one needs to be true.

In addition, the interval trigger creates the next fire time by adding the interval  to the current time at the time of execution.

Interpreting this as strictly as possible, it means in your example it will always only use the 10 second trigger.

Now as for getting the trigger, the trigger is an attribute of the job object, so you cannot access it from the function. Even so, getting the job object by its id with `job = scheduler.get_job(id)` and then `trigger = job.trigger` would give you the whole combined trigger as you defined it.